# Does a monotone subadditive $f: \mathcal{P}(\bf N)\to [0,1]$ admit a finite partition with values in $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A function $f\colon \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{N})\to [0,1]$ is said to have the *Darboux property* whenever for all $X \subseteq \mathbf{N}$ and $y \in [0,f(X)]$, there exists $Y \subseteq X$ such that $f(Y)=y$.

Moreover, $f$ is said to be *monotone* if $f(X)\le f(Y)$ whenever $X\subseteq Y$ and *subadditive* if $f(X\cup Y) \le f(X)+f(Y)$ for all $X,Y \subseteq \mathbf{N}$.

> **Question.** Let $f\colon \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{N})\to [0,1]$ be a monotone subadditive function with the Darboux property such that $f(\mathbf{N})=1$. Does there exist necessarily a *finite* partition $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ of $\mathbf{N}$ for which
>   $$
> f(A_1), \ldots, f(A_k) \in (0,1)?
> $$

---

A simpler version of this question has been posted on MSE one week ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457731/a-monotone-subadditive-non-atomic-f-on-the-power-of-bf-n-hasa-partition-a), showing that in general the answer is negative if $k$ is bounded.

The question comes from the study of properties of a class of functions satisfying certain axioms, which can be called as "upper densities" (with this respect, you can see this MO [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214878/additivity-of-upper-densities-with-respect-to-arithmetic-progressions-of-integer)). [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219274/reference-request-darboux-properties-of-real-valued-set-functions-measures-de), instead, there is MO question related to the definition of Darboux property.

A related construction (which does not ask for subadditivity) by [Salvo Tringali](https://mathoverflow.net/users/16537/salvo-tringali?tab=profile) has been provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404968/does-darboux-property-imply-strong-darboux-property).

Comment: What's wrong with this rather trivial construction: Choose $A_1\subseteq \mathbb N$ with $f(A_1)=1/2$. Because of subadditivity, $1=f(A_1 \cup A_1^c)\le f(A_1)+f(A_1^c)$ so that $f(A_1^c)\ge 1/2$. Next choose $A_2\subseteq A_1^c$ with $f(A_2)=1/4$. As above $f(A_1^c \cup A_2^c)\ge 1/4$. Continue in that way.

Comment: Why do you expect to stop in a finite number of steps?

Comment: If you want to stop at a given $k$, just take $A_k=\mathbb N \setminus (A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{k-1})$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth. Of course. But only if you can prove that $0 < f((A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_k)^c) < 1$ for some $k$, in your construction. In principle, you don't have any information on the behaviour of $f(A^c)$ for $A \subseteq \mathbf N$ and $f(A) > 0$ (if $f(A) = 0$, it is seen that $f(A^c) = 1$).

Comment: Okay, I see the problem. For $k=2$ and $A_2=A_1^c$ it may happen that $f(A_2)=1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\let\eps\varepsilon$It seems that the following function fits:
$$
  f(A)=\inf\left\{\alpha\colon \quad \sum_{x\in A}x^{-\alpha}<\infty\right\}.
$$
(I assume that $\mathbb N$ starts with 1.)
Clearly, it is monotone, and $f(\mathbb N)=1$. Moreover, it is more than subadditive: we have $f(A\cup B)=\max\{f(A),f(B)\}$. This also implies that if $A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_k=\mathbb N$, then $f(A_i)=1$ for some $i$.

It remains to show that $f$ has the Darboux property. Let $f(A)=\alpha$ and $\beta\in[0,\alpha)$; we need to find $B\subseteq A$ with $f(B)=\beta$. We have $\sum_{x\in A}x^{-\beta}=\infty$. Set $X_n=[2^n,2^{n+1})\cap \mathbb N$, $A_n=A\cap X_n$, and $a_n=\sum_{x\in A_n}x^{-\beta}$.  Then the series $\sum_n a_n$ diverges.

Set $b_n=\min\{a_n,1\}$. The series $\sum_n b_n$ diverges as well (this is trivial if $b_i=1$ infinitely many times, as well as if it happens only finitely many times). Now, choose $B_n$ to be the subset of  $A_n$ such that $S_n=\sum_{x\in B_n}x^{-\beta}\leq b_n$, and $S_n$ is maximal subject to this property. Then $S_n\geq b_n/2$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Set $B=\cup_n B_n$; then $\sum_{x\in B}x^{-\beta}\geq \sum_n b_n/2=\infty$. On the other hand, for every $\eps>0$ we have
$$
  \sum_{x\in B}=
  \sum_n\sum_{x\in B_n}x^{-\beta-\eps}
  \leq \sum_n 2^{-\eps n}\sum_{x\in B_n}x^{-\beta}
  \leq \sum_n2^{-\eps n}<\infty.
$$
Thus $f(B)=\beta$.

Comment: Very nice. Incidentally, the fnc in this example is also shift-invariant, i.e. $f(X + h) = f(X)$ for all $X \subseteq \mathbf N$ and $h \in \mathbf N$ (immediate by the limit comparison test), and has the strong Darboux property, too: If $A\subseteq B\subseteq \mathbf N$ and $\gamma \in {]f(A), f(B)[}$, then $f$ being weakly Darboux implies the existence of a set $C\subseteq B$ s.t. $f(C) = \gamma$, and hence $f(A \cup C) = \max(f(A), f(C)) = \gamma$. Since, of course, $A \subseteq A \cup C \subseteq B$, that is enough to conclude.

Comment: It's very similar (the same?) to take $f(A) = \limsup\,\log|A\cap\{1,\dots,n\}|/\log n.$ This is something like the "upper dimension" of a set of integers.

Comment: @SeanEberhard. The fnc in your comment is sometimes called the upper exponential density; see, e.g., G. G. Lorentz, _On a problem of additive number theory_, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **5** (1954), No. 5, 838-841, or Section 4 in: G. Grekos, _On various definitions of density (survey)_, Tatra Mt. Math. Publ. **31** (2005), 17-27. But I don't know if it's the same as the fnc in Ilya Bogdanov's example.

Comment: Anyway, this upper exponential density also seems to work.

Comment: @SeanEberhard. You were right. The fnc in Ilya's answer is called the convergence exponent in the 1st vol. of Pólya and Szegö's *Problems and Theorems in Analysis* (Pt. I, Chap. 3, Sect. 2), and Exercise 113 on p. 26 (which is solved on pp. 202-203) asks to prove that it is equal to $\limsup_n\frac{\log n}{\log x_n}$, where $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is the natural enumeration of the set $X$ (assuming $|X|=\infty$), and now it's not difficult to see that this latter limit is nothing but the upper exponential density mentioned in your comment.